# Generating contingency summary table in LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

```
> dput(mydat)
structure(list(Q1 = c(0, 1, NA, 1), Q2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), Q3 = c(1, 
NA, 1, 1), Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor"), Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B")), .Names = c("Q1", 
"Q2", "Q3", "Gender", "Type"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

> mydat
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Gender Type
1  0  0  1      M    A
2  1  1 NA      M    A
3 NA  1  1      F    A
4  1  1  1      F    B
```

I have a data.frame with 3 questions and 2 demographic variables. I've written a function to output a summary table.

```
myfun <- function(from, to){
  tt = t(rowsum(mydat[from:to], mydat$Gender, na.rm = TRUE))
  ptt = prop.table(tt, 2)
  fish = fisher.test(tt, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
  tt2 = t(rowsum(mydat[from:to], mydat$Type, na.rm = TRUE))
  ptt2 = prop.table(tt2, 2)
  fish2 = fisher.test(tt2, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
  list(rbind(cbind(Female = tt[, 1], ptt[, 1], Male = tt[, 2], ptt[, 2],
                          A = tt2[, 1], ptt2[, 1], B = tt2[, 2], ptt2[, 2]),
              c(fish$p.value, NA, NA, NA, fish2$p.value, NA, NA, NA)))
}

tab = myfun(1, 2)
>tab

[[1]]
   Female           Male     A            B    
Q1      1 0.3333333    1 0.5 1 0.3333333  1 0.5
Q2      2 0.6666667    1 0.5 2 0.6666667  1 0.5
        1        NA   NA  NA 1        NA NA  NA
```

This function takes in 2 parameters (from, to) that tells the functions which questions I want to select. In my example I selected questions 1 and 2. I wanted the function to output a count and its corresponding proportion. And the last row of the table is a p-value that reflects the association between the questions and a demographic variable (Gender or Type).

```
xtable(data.frame(tab))
```

Calling the above function gives the following LaTeX table:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Where the entries in the table are displayed as `count (proportion)` in each cell instead of having a separate column for the proportions. Is there a more efficient way to do this? In Hmisc maybe?

Comment: You may check `tables::tabfreq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer using knitr, xtable, and the [tabularX](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package.

The tabularX package will ensure that the width of the document is filled by the X columns. It is called with the options `tabular.environment = "tabularx"`and `width="\\textwidth"` in the `print.xtable` method and I use the option `align(xt)<-c("l","X","X","X","X")` so that my X columns width span the remaining width of the page.

In your example you wanted to paste two values (numbers and probabilities), this is simply done by calling `str_c(str_c(tt[, 1]," (",ptt[, 1],")")`, `str_c()`is like `paste()`but by default the separator is "". When creating a data.frame the unique values ")" and ")" are repeated to match the number of rows of the table.

The major problem is that the last row has only two columns. So I'm using the `add.to.row` argument to xtable to define a customary line. I specify at which row I want to add custom values, here it is the last (line 2) hence `addtorow$pos[[1]] <- 2`, and then I add an argument saying that the row will span two columns.

```
addtorow$command <- str_c(" p-Value & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{",fish$p.value,"} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{", fish2$p.value,"} \\\\\n")
```

As I'm doing this inside the function, I return a list of two elements, the first is the table, the second the add.to.row argument.

So finally, my table looks like :

```
% latex table generated in R 3.4.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Mon Oct 30 21:50:04 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXXX}
  \hline
 & Female & Male & A & B \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 (0.33) & 1 (0.5) & 1 (0.33) & 1 (0.5) \\ 
  2 & 2 (0.67) & 1 (0.5) & 2 (0.67) & 1 (0.5) \\ 
    p-Value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

which produces

[image: table with two different row length]

Here is the knitr code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Test example for table with different row length}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\date{} % no date
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}


<<init, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide'>>=
require(stringr)
require(xtable)
@

<<table_example, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide'>>=
require(stringr)
require(xtable)
mydat <- structure(list(Q1 = c(0, 1, NA, 1), Q2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), Q3 = c(1, NA, 1, 
                1), Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
            Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B")), .Names = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Gender", "Type"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

myfun <- function(from, to) {
  tt <- t(rowsum(mydat[, from:to], mydat$Gender, na.rm = TRUE))
  ptt <- round(prop.table(tt, 2), 2)
  fish <- fisher.test(tt, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
  tt2 <- t(rowsum(mydat[, from:to], mydat$Type, na.rm = TRUE))
  ptt2 <- round(prop.table(tt2, 2), 2)
  fish2 <- fisher.test(tt2, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
  df <- data.frame(Female = str_c(tt[, 1], " (", ptt[, 1], ")"), Male = str_c(tt[, 
                      2], " (", ptt[, 2], ")"), A = str_c(tt2[, 1], " (", ptt2[, 1], ")"), B = str_c(tt2[, 
                      2], " (", ptt2[, 2], ")"))
  addtorow <- list()
  addtorow$pos <- list()
  addtorow$pos[[1]] <- 2
  addtorow$command <- str_c(" p-Value & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{", fish$p.value, "} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{", 
      fish2$p.value, "} \\\\\n")
  return(list(df = df, addtorow = addtorow))
}
tab = myfun(1, 2)$df
addtorow = myfun(1, 2)$addtorow
xt <- xtable(tab)
align(xt) <- c("l", "X", "X", "X", "X")
print.xtable(x = xt, file = "test_table_out.tex", tabular.environment = "tabularx", 
    width = "\\textwidth", add.to.row = addtorow)
@
\input{test_table_out.tex}
\end{document}
```